# run php code before joomla users logout

Tags: php, joomla

I wrote a component for Joomla that site users can book an appointment
I want to execute the php code when the user leaves the site so that if the operation is not successful, the payment of that booking will be deleted from the database.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should develop a User plugin and use Joomla events for firing your codes on related events. https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User

onUserLogout

> This event is triggered before the user is logged out of the system.
>
> If any plugin returns false, the global logout fails and the
>   onUserLogoutFailure event is fired; if it succeeds, onUserAfterLogout
>   event is triggered instead.

Also you can find a complete tutorial about developing a plugin here: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla